# Codeigniter - No Data Received - Not Chrome related

Tags: linux, codeigniter

I've found plenty of versions of this questions, but neither seem to go further than an apparent Google Chrome bug.

What happens is that whenever I copy a codeigniter setup to a new folder on my server, to start a new project based on it, I get "no data received" in any browser I try it on.

The strange part is that the problem is solved if I go into each file that gets include()-d, add or change something irrelevant (like a blank space) and save the file. I don't know why, but this makes that specific include() work. Otherwise, the script stops before it.

There's nothing logged in the server's access or error logs so I can't figure out what the problem might be.

Needless to say this has been driving me crazy. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you say you use include() in you codeigniter project?

Comment: Hi @MatteoT., I meant the normal included/required files that codeigniter uses.

Comment: Can u tell us more about your setup? Are you using .htaccess, are you removing index.php from url, did you change your config file, are you using error_reporting(E_ALL) to see errors that occur, do you have any databases, and so on. If you are getting blank page I could guess you don't have your error reporting on so you can't see any errors. PS: codeigniter rather loads then includes, which is the same thing eventually but that's how they call it. That's why I was confused.

Comment: @MatteoT. my sysadmin figured it out. It was because of system-wide APC cache. I used apc_clear_cache once and everything worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sysadmin figured it out. It was related to system wide APC cache. I used apc_clear_cache() at the top of index.php and everything works like a charm!